# How to create a temporary discord invite with a discord bot and send it to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a discord invite with my discord bot and after getting the invite link I want to send it as an response and that invite should expire after 15 mins, so how can I do this and please tell me if there's any limit to requests or not.

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Guild } from "discord.js";
import { DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN, DISCORD_SERVER_ID, PORT } from "./constants.js";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Discord Client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
});

app.get("/", () => {
  console.log("works");
});

app.get("/generate-invite", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const server = client.guilds.cache.get(DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
    // Send the invite URL in the response
    // res.json({ inviteUrl: invite.url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to generate invite" });
  }
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`);
});

client.login(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

I am failing to access that server object it says something like <ref *2> in my terminal tell me what's this too and how to access this too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [createInvite()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseGuildTextChannel?scrollTo=createInvite) method from on a text channel and specify the `maxAge` in the [InviteCreateOptions](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/InviteCreateOptions).

```js
server.createInvite({ maxAge: 15 * 60 }).then((inviteLink) => {/* do whatever with the invite here */})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `createInvite()` method from any [GuildChannel](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10#GuildChannelType). You will have to specifiy an [InviteCreateOptions](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.13.0/typedef/InviteCreateOptions) object with your expiration age.

---

The code should look something like this:

```js
const server = client.guilds.cache.get(DISCORD_SERVER_ID); // put the guild ID
const channel = server.channels.find(DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID); // put the channel ID

channel.createInvite({ 
   maxAge: 15 * 60, // max age in seconds (15 minutes here)
   reason: "Generated via /generate-invite command" // (reason: optional)
}).then((inviteURL) => {
   res.json({
      invite: {
         url: inviteURL
      }
   })
});
```